# Color-depth in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, color-depth

I made a promotional video for my Exoplanet app and just noticed that the color-depth on the iPhone simulator is much lower than on the physical device. The visualizations look splendid on the actual phone but rather cheap on the simulator. I mainly notice this when using textures in OpenGL and CoreAnimation.

Have a look at [this short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDBZQTcGbT8&hd=1) to see what I mean. (It has nothing to do with the recording.)

Am I doing something wrong? Can I increase the color-depth of the simulator?